# How to specify return type of a function when returning multiple values?

Tags: python-3.x, function, types, return

In Python, we can specify the return type of function as

```
def foo() -> int:
    some_int = get_some_int()
    return some_int
```

How to specify return types when returning multiple values? For example, how would one specify return types for the following function?

```
def bar(): # -> ?
    some_float = get_some_float()
    some_int = get_some_int()
    return some_float,some_int
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are only returning one type whcih is a tuple which then contains your float and your int. but the function its self returns a tuple. You can annotate this with type hint like.

```
from typing import Tuple

def bar() -> Tuple[float, int]:
    some_float = get_some_float()
    some_int = get_some_int()
    return some_float,some_int
```