# How do I change the format in which a function is displayed when using print()? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I change the format in which multiple return values from a function are displayed. When I print the function, the two return values are displayed inside parentheses. Is there a way to change this?

```
def test():
    x = 1 + 1
    y = 2 + 2
    return x, y
print(test())
```

This prints the following: (2, 4)

I would like for it to be displayed like this: 2 and 4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify return type of a function when returning multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59049760/how-to-specify-return-type-of-a-function-when-returning-multiple-values)

Comment: The thing is I am trying to format the way it is displayed when I print the actual function. Is there a way that I can format the way the return values are displayed when printing the function?

Comment: Your code does not "print the function", it prints the return value. Calling a function is an action, not a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string format:

```py
def test():
    return 1, 2


print("%s and %s" % (test()))
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting) and [here](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) you can read more about its functionalities.